# Getting column number in source generators (IIncrementalGenerator)

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I am currently working on some source generators in combination with
interceptors.
As basis, I used this documentation:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/interceptors.md

My problem is the following:
Given the following code:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public void TestFunc()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to intercept the Bar call here. Retrieving the
filename for the cs file is pretty straightforward - also, retrieving
the line number.

```cs
var path = GetInterceptorFilePath(context.Node.SyntaxTree,
context.SemanticModel.Compilation);
var line = context.SemanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(context.Node.Span).StartLinePosition.Line
+ 1;
```

The problem starts when trying to get the character.

My approaches so far: `context.SemanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(context.Node.Span).Span.Start.Character`.
But that returns just 1; it seems this will not take whitespace into account.
The next: `context.Node.ToString().IndexOf("Bar", StringComparison.Ordinal)`
This will also ignore whitespace.

That said, what is the correct approach?

Also, consider that people sometimes use tabs or spaces - tabs can have
different lengths. And I am not sure how this is considered
for the interceptors.
The documentation here doesn't reveal more, either.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the syntax node for the `InvocationExpressionSyntax`, then you can use a `.GetLocation()` on that node. It will give you a `Location` object, from where you will find the filepath and the `SourceSpan` object with the start, end and length of the invocation.

Comment: FIY, this is also the 'Location' object used to generate diagnostics, so it should be as close to correct as you can come.

Comment: I tried your solution - it did give me some numbers, but they weren't correct.
I ended up with:
context.SemanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(context.Node.Span).Span.Start.Character, which seems to work in my cases

Comment: @Link Does it seem to be the correct location for you or your interceptor? Does your interceptor work with your solution?

Comment: To some degree - yes. At least on my local machine (MacOS) and the Ubuntu GitHub runner - but there seem to be issues with the windows runner. Once I have more time, I try to find out what is going on.